# Faster than Light "Distribution"

Tags: electromagnetism, information

Signals cannot propagate faster than light, but let us say I have some some charge distribution which produces an electric field such that it has a peak at some point. Can I vary the source charge distribution in such a way that the "peak" itself moves faster than light? Is there a limit to how fast this peak can move?

Note that a peak is not an individual wavefront: it is simply a point where the electric field has maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pattern where one can use several different frequencies, and line them all up to have a "group velocity" that is higher than the speed of light.  This is not a violation of the rules because the peak is built on top of information that did indeed travel at the speed of light.

You may also be interested in ["what is the speed of dark?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ).  They don't explore electomagnatism per se, but they do show several geometric patterns which lead to non-information traveling faster than light.